# Huawei: FCM only received immediately when app is running or phone is charging

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, huawei-mobile-services

My Android app does not receive FCM push messages immediately, if the phone is on standby and not currently charging. I think I really set everything I could in the phone settings regarding energy saving... Is there something I can do in the app itself?

It works on other manufacturers but on our Huawei it doesn't...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

These phones tend to kill all background app. I mean no sticly service and broadcast receivers as well. Try whitelisting your app from battery settings. It will prevent your app from getting killed by system

Comment: `Try whitelisting your app from battery settings` - I think I did everything I could in the phone settings... Whatsapp for example gets the notifications immediately, so I guess there must be a way to achieve this...

Comment: These manufacturers automatically exempt major apps from getting killed. Like whatsapp and facebook. I have an app where i have to keep my service running. My users face the same issue, i advise them to exempt my app from battery saver and it works

Comment: where exactly do they exempt your app from battery saver?